# Setting fallback font in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context

How does one set an emoji font as a fallback in ConTeXt?

MWE is basically, following the [contextgarden/simplefonts](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/simplefonts) instructions:

```
\definefontfamily [main] [serif] [Minion Pro]
\definefallbackfamily[main] [serif] [Noto Emoji] [range=emoticon,force=yes]
```

Noto Emoji is a free emoticon font from Google, available under SIL at: https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/tree/master/fonts

The job log reports:

> selectfont      > The requested fallback font 'Noto Emoji' for typeface 'main' style 'rm' was ignored because no files where found.

The command `mtxrun --script font --list noto` shows:

> notoemoji   notoemoji   /home/user/fonts/NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf

I've tracked the error down to http://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkiv/font-sel.lua
in `selectfont.definefallbackfamily`, but I'm not familiar enough to guess what might be the issue here.

**[edit]** Incidentally: `context --version` returns: `ConTeXt Process Management 0.63` and `current version: 2017.01.27 14:39`; it also exhibits on MacTeX with version `2016.10.22 10:43`

**[edit]** There seems to be some difference in the latest ConTeXt standalone, so I suspect there may be issues "on the edge".  In any case, here's a full MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = ConTeXt (LuaTeX)
\enabletrackers[selectfont.register,selectfont.files,selectfont.alternatives]
\definefontfamily [main] [serif] [Minion Pro]
\definefallbackfamily[main] [serif] [Noto Emoji] [range=emoticon,force=yes]
\setupbodyfont[main]

\starttext
  Hello.  Some valid Noto Emoji:    ⌛  ⏳  ⌚ 
\stoptext
```

**[edit]** Here's a sample of the unicode range included:

> \definefallbackfamily[main] [serif] [Noto Emoji] [force=yes,range={emoticons,dingbats,miscellaneoussymbols,ornamentaldingbats,miscellaneousmathematicalsymbolsa,miscellaneousmathematicalsymbolsb,miscellaneoussymbols,miscellaneoussymbolsandarrows,miscellaneoussymbolsandpictographs,miscellaneoustechnical}]

Further ranges can be seen in `context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/char-ini.lua`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set a fallback font for `\definefontfamily`, put all `\definefallbackfamily` settings before the main font. You *must* use the correct arguments for the `range` key. In your case, use `miscellaneoussymbols` and `dingbats` (and probably a few more):

```
\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [serif] [Noto Emoji] [range={miscellaneoussymbols,dingbats}]
\definefontfamily     [mainface] [serif] [Minion Pro]

\setupbodyfont[mainface]

\starttext
Noto Emoji symbols: \utfchar{"26F5} \utfchar{"2712}
\stoptext
```

[image: Noto Emoji as fallback font for Minion Pro]

As another example, to define [Gentium Plus](https://software.sil.org/gentium/download/) as the font fallback family for Greek fonts, you could use:

```
\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [serif] [Gentium Plus] [range=greekandcoptic]
```

See [`\definefontfallback`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definefontfallback) for more details about character ranges.

Comment: Thanks – I noted you used `\utfchar`; is it possible to embed the UTF characters directly?

Comment: Yes you can also use the characters itself in your document.

Comment: Is there a way to set it up so the `range` parameter is unnecessary?

Comment: You need the range setting but you can use a wider range (e.g. `range=0x00000-0xFFFFF`) without forcing a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

try with another naming, like

```
\definefallbackfamily[main] [serif] [Noto Emoji Regular] [range=emoticon,force=yes]
```

or this

```
\definefallbackfamily[main] [serif] [file: NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf] [range=emoticon,force=yes]
```

**EDIT**
what about this? (even without "regular")

```
  \definefallbackfamily[main] [serif] [notoemojiregular] [range=emoticon,force=yes]
```

Comment: I tried `notoemoji` and `notoemojiregular` too, but they also did not work.